# UNIX: Using sed to eliminate and replace things in a string?

Tags: regex, string, unix, sed, awk

I have a string, lets say:

```
<lic><ic>This is a string</ic>, welcome to my blog.</lic>
```

I want to use sed to get rid of the `<ic>` and `</ic>` tags, as well as the literal tags `<lic>` and `</lic>`

What is the fastest way to do this? I'm very new to sed. How would this be done in awk?
I know awk is much better for column-like text, so I feel more inclined to learn how to use sed.

Any help is always appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: _Just_ those tags? No others?

Comment: You do not want to use sed to parse xml:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -e 's%</\{0,1\}l\{0,1\}ic>%%g'
```

The `\{0,1\}` is the standard `sed` way of writing the equivalent of `?` in PCRE.  The regex uses `%` to separate bits; then looks for an `<` possibly followed by a slash, possibly followed by an `l`, followed by `ic>` and replaces it with nothing, globally across each line of input.

Some versions of `sed` allow you to specify alternative systems of regexes, but this works everywhere.

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked on the first try! Do you by chance know how this would be done using awk?

Comment: I'm sure it could be done with `awk`; I would not use `awk` for the job, though.  I'd use Perl, where it would be 'trivial': `perl -pe 's%</?l?ic>%%g'`.  In situ overwirting of the files with backup is available too.  With `gawk`, the function would be `gsub`: `awk '{gsub(/<\/?l?ic>/, '', $0); print;}'`.  Untested code.

Comment: As you said, some versions of `sed` support additional regex features. At least in GNU `sed`, `\?` works (or with `-r`: `?`).

Answer (score 3):

Remove only tags:

```
sed -i.old -r 's;</?l?ic>;;g' infile
```

Comment: +1 for most concise answer. `sed 's|</\?l\?ic>||g' infile` would work too or if you prefer `sed 's|</*l*ic>||g'` at a pinch.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` doesn't need to be complicated. Here are two simple ways to do what you want.

This matches those exact patterns and removes them globally:

`sed -e "s%\(<lic>\|</lic>\|<ic>\|</ic>\)%%g" file.txt`

Remember, that you can set multiple expressions using `sed` if necessary:

`sed -e "s%<lic>%%" -e "s%</lic>%%" -e "s%<ic>%%" -e "s%</ic>%%" file.txt`

Comment: Also, if you change `-e` to `-i`, you can write those changes to `file.txt` directly.

Comment: An alternative is `sed 's%<\(/l\|/\|l\|\)ic>%%g' file.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Your tags have a structure of a left bracket followed by a number of characters that are not a right bracket and then finally a right bracket. So let's write it that way:

```
sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
```